# [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index]

Tags: datagridview

What does this mean? What is the problem in this code?

[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index]
System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index) +13873403
FAMS.UserMaintenance.gvUse_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e) +102
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.OnRowCommand(GridViewCommandEventArgs e) +139
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +95
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +50
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +145
System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1964

Comment: Well presumably the problem is in your `FAMS.UserMaintenance.gvUse_RowCommand` method... please show the code for that method.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not a programmer type of guy, can you help me find where is it located? any instructions would be greatly appreciated. I got this problem while updating or resetting a user password.

Comment: You need to find whoever maintains the code. Trying to fix this without any programming experience is going to be frustrating for you and anyone trying to help you, I'm afraid.